# Error while fetch data from db with neo4j-go-driver connection

Tags: go, neo4j

```
    if err != nil {
        logger.Log.Printf("DEBUG:1 GetStockComments : s%", err.Error())
        return []Comment{}, err
    }
    var records []Comment

    comment := Comment{}
    for result.Next() {
        record := result.Record()
        if value, ok := record.Get("c"); ok {
            node := value.(neo4j.Node)
            props := node.Props()
            err := mapstructure.Decode(props, &comment)
            if err != nil {
                logger.Log.Printf("DEBUG:2 GetStockComments : s%", err.Error())
                return []Comment{}, err
            }
            records = append(records, comment)
        }
    }
```

Some time on Session.run, result.Next()
Error not shown on the postman, when I try to run APIs in sequence using code then it will happen

```
runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 122 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0002ba500)
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/net/http/server.go:1767 +0x139
panic(0x964400, 0xf64c70)
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/panic.go:679 +0x1b2
github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/neo4j.(*result).doFetch(0xc0001f7b00, 0x0)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver@v1.8.3/neo4j/result.go:73 +0x32
github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/neo4j.(*result).fetchAll(0xc0001f7b00)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver@v1.8.3/neo4j/result.go:134 +0x31
github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/neo4j.(*session).consumeCurrent(0xc00020e000, 0x1, 0x0)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver@v1.8.3/neo4j/session.go:433 +0x34
github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/neo4j.(*session).Run(0xc00020e000, 0xa1ec6a, 0x8b, 0xc000703860, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0002d6a80, 0x7f8ecca62008, 0x0, ...)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver@v1.8.3/neo4j/session.go:450 +0x4a
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue, I just start DB session on project start, but I need to start and close on every query run. This solved my problem, thanks all...